# Android File Hosting - Only allow the app access its drive

Tags: android, file-upload, download, google-drive-api, secure-coding

I've been searching and can't find what I am looking for. So I am hoping that you can help me. Here is what I want to do...

I want to write a TV app. The app needs to have a list of channels (saved in a text file). I know how to do this, but I need help with allowing users to share their channels with other users. So here is my idea...

1. I can setup a google drive, dropbox, etc... so users can upload/download channels (text files) to/from this share drive (I will own this drive and only I can have access to it)
2. When user browse for new channels in my app, my app should get a list of files from the drive and then display those file names on the screen. User then pick one of those files, the app will import the channels from the selected file.
3. When user want to share their channels, they click on a share button from my app. The app will save the channels to a text file and then upload this file to the Drive.

My question is, how can I write code to securely access the drive AND only allow my app to access the file. I do not want anyone or any other app to access my Drive.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File servers are not correct for this type of data, it is okay to create a webservice, use a mysql server and write a script in php to manage the use of these data.

See this tutorial:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm

Comment: How can i secure the web services so that ONLY my app can access it?

Comment: authenticate a token sented by the client

Answer (score 0):

Example of secury token:

```
if(addslashes($_GET['token'])=="my token"){

   //my code

}else{
   echo "invalid token";
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is hacker proof. What if user root the device and can access this token? I'll read up on this to learn more about it. Thank you for your help. Now if i still want to do the file way, can you help me with the original question? Or can someone please?

Comment: Encrypts and stores the token in UserPrefs. 
To send a request to the server read the UserPrefs Encrypted and decrypt the token and send with others informations.